# How to output failed test results to the console with 'spec' and 'mocha-multi-reporters'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp, mocha.js

I'm having issues outputting test-failure reasons when I use '**spec**' as a reporter with '**mocha-multi-reporters**' as part of server-side testing with gulp.

For instance, when I set the mocha reporter to '**spec**' in the standard format like below:

```
.pipe(plugins.mocha({
        reporter: 'spec',
        timeout: 10000
      }))
```

I get the following console-output:

```
Search
1) should be able to get empty search-result list
2) should be able to get search-result list with one element


0 passing (458ms)
2 failing

  1) Search GET should be able to get empty search-result list:
     AssertionError: expected Array [] to have property length of 1 (got 0)

  2) Search GET should be able to get search-result list with 2 elements:
     AssertionError: expected Array [] to have property length of 2 (got 0)
```

---

However, when I set '**spec**' as a reporter as part of '**mocha-multi-reporters**' like below:

```
.pipe(plugins.mocha({
        reporter: 'mocha-multi-reporters',
        reporterOptions: { "reporterEnabled": "spec" },
        timeout: 10000
      }))
```

My console output does not display the first 2 reasons for failure, instead it adds an additional failure and only logs that one:

```
Search
1) should be able to get empty search-result list
2) should be able to get search-result list with one element

0 passing (528ms)
2 failing

  3) "after each" hook
error:  message=3 tests failed., showStack=false, showProperties=true, plugin=gulp-mocha, toString=function () { [native code] }
```

---

I've tried looking into many online resources as to why this may be the case but had no luck.
Does anybody know why this may be happening? The reason I'm using **mocha-multi-reporters** now is so that we can also use **mocha-allure-reporter** as part of test-failure logging.

---

For reference, I'm using the following plugin versions:

- "mocha": "5.2.0"
- "mocha-multi-reporters": "1.1.7"
- "gulp": "4.0.0"
- "should": "13.2.3" ***(For assertion testing)***